# Get iframe url variable from inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jquery/javascript if possible and grab a url variable frim inside the iframe

my iframe link looks like the below - the source changes dynamically

```
<iframe class="box" src="lightbox.html?img=images/lightbox/blue-shoes.jpg" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Then, from inside the lightbox.html iframe - I want to grab the img (images/lightbox/blue-shoes.jpg) variable and change the source of an image

problem is - I cant figure out how to grab the iframe source url variable from inside the iframe

I am trying to avoid using php

I have used this for something similiar but cant get it to work

```
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = document.referrer.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}
var first = getUrlVars()["ref"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you control the script inside the iframe, here is an example that uses document.location.herf instead of referrer.  lightbox.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = document.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
    }
    var first = getUrlVars()["img"];
    alert(first);
    var test = function(){
        first = 'images/red.jpg'
        alert(first);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>Inside</div>
    <button onclick="test()">change url</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this using JQuery try this.

The image on your page lightbox.html, give it ad id e.g.

```
<img id="ImageID" src="whatever" />
```

Then use this JQuery to change the src attribute

```
$('#ImageID').attr('src', 'whatever');
```

UPDATE

in fact this probably won't work due to it being an IFrame I believe you won't be allowed to do this due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)